# joining two tables together

Tags: t-sql

I have a `select` query that returns two columns in the following way. I can put this in a temp table or make it a CTE if it helps solving the problem. The problem is listed later on.

```
id     (cnt)
28002   11
28010   14
28029   13
28037   7
28045   6
28053   3
28061   6
28070   5
28100   5
28118   10
29009   1
```

but I now wanna select from another table which has the following definition

```
id
sub_id
numberOfObjects
```

so sample data could be

```
id      sub_id    numberofObjects
28002   203125        10
28002   203126        56
28002   203127        75
28002   203128        76
28002   203129        5
28002   203130        50
28061   203131        26
28061   203132        7
28061   203133        14
28061   203134        32
29009   105678        33
```

so as you can see, one `id` has many `sub_id`.

### My goal:

For each id in the first select statement, I want it to match that id in the second select statement and pull all sub_ids where the numberOfObjects is less then 15

so my result should be

```
id      sub_id    numberofObjects
28002   203125        10

28002   203129        5

28061   203132        7
28061   203133        14
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
SELECT f.id
    , ot.sub_id
    , ot.numberofobjects
FROM 
      ( ...first query...) f
JOIN otherTable ot
  ON ot.id = f.id
WHERE ot.numberofobjects < 15
```

If you want the main id to appear even if no subid's have fewer than 15...

```
SELECT f.id
    , ot.sub_id
    , ot.numberofobjects
FROM 
      ( ...first query...) f
LEFT JOIN otherTable ot
  ON ot.id = f.id
  AND ot.numberofobjects < 15
```

And yes, you could use a CTE instead of an inline view.